# Configure docker daemon logs

Tags: docker

I'm trying to modify the file that the daemon log its activity and all I can get is to log into /var/log/messages. Is it possible to alter it to point to /var/log/docker/docker.log or something like that? Thanks

Comment: You can always redirect stdout to that file `> var/log/docker/docker.log`. How are you running the daemon?

Comment: I'm running it with the default options under RHEL with "systemctl start docker"

Comment: Also I'm checking https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/ but there's no reference about changing the file where daemon output logs.

Comment: I'm trying to configure Rsyslog with these two lines:
`if $programname == 'docker' then /var/log/docker.log`
`if $programname == 'docker' then stop` as seen on http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Filtering_by_program_name, it actually works but there should be a more elegant way to perform the same on the docker daemon

Comment: The docker daemon doesn't output to a file, it only outputs to stdout/stderr. I believe it's systemd that is taking stdout and sending it to a file, so you have to configure it in systemd or rsyslog, as you're doing above.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved that using Rsyslog with these two lines:

```
if $programname == 'docker' then /var/log/docker.log
if $programname == 'docker' then stop
```

as seen on wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Filtering_by_program_name, it actually works but there should be a more elegant way to perform the same on the docker daemon.

Comment: On ubunt16 with latest version of docker I had to use 'dockerd' as program name.